# when training simple code of pytorch, cpu ratio increased. GPU is 0% approximately

Tags: python, visual-studio-2017, gpu, pytorch

I'm doing tutorial of [Pytorch](https://pytorch.org/tutorials/beginner/blitz/cifar10_tutorial.html).

Code is clearly completed. but i have one problem.

It is about my CPU use ratio.
If I enter into training, CPU usage ratio is increasıng up to 100%.
but GPU is roughly 0%.

I installed `CUDA 9.2` and `cudnn`. 
and I already checked massage about `torch.cuda.is_available()==True`.

is it OK, or my setup is wrong?

Comment: Can you add whether or not you tried moving individual tensors to GPU first, and see if you can (manually) perform operations on the GPU before starting the training? Did you make sure that everything is available to the GPU, and your model is defined on the right device as well?
Also, did you by any chance install `pytorch-cpu` instead of the "fully fledged" install?

Comment: @dennlinger thanks your comment. i add my code like this :   device = torch.device("cuda:0" if torch.cuda.is_available() else "cpu")
        inputs, labels = data
        # Assuming that we are on a CUDA machine, this should print a CUDA device:
        # print(device)
        inputs, labels = inputs.to(device), labels.to(device)
        net.to(device) // is this clear? now Cpu ratio is 23%, gpu is 3% :(

Comment: Please add your code as an edit to the question, and not into the comments, for better visibility.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1.. Did you upload your model and input tensors onto GPU explicitly, showing as follow
https://pytorch.org/tutorials/beginner/blitz/cifar10_tutorial.html#training-on-gpu

For example,

```
# Configure your device
device = torch.device("cuda:0" if torch.cuda.is_available() else "cpu")
# Upload your model onto GPU
net.to(device)
# Upload your tensor onto GPU
inputs, labels = inputs.to(device), labels.to(device)
```

2.. You also can use "gpustat" to check GPU usage.
https://github.com/wookayin/gpustat

After installing, you can type "gpustat" on terminal
If your code runs on GPU, GPU usage will increase.

3.. And check whether you've added following CUDA path into your bashrc file.
Following CUDA path is general path on Ubuntu Linux,
but that path can be different per OS or your setting.

You can open bashrc file by typing vim ./.bashrc
when your current directory is home in case where you use Ubuntu Linux.

```
export PATH=/usr/local/cuda/bin:$PATH
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/cuda/lib64:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
```

4.. Also check your graphic driver has been installed 
by typing nvidia-smi on terminal if you use Ubuntu Linux.